# Include a module for all routes at express.js 4

Tags: node.js, express, express-4

I'm using Express 4.2.0

Is it possible to include a module **only once** in app.js and use it in any defined route?

Right now this won't work:

**app.js**

```
//..
var request = require('request');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
//...
```

**routes/user.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/add', function(req, res) {
    var session = req.session;
    request('http://localhost:8181/Test?val1=getDepartments', function (error, response, body) {
       //...
    });

    res.render('users/add');
});

module.exports = router;
```

It will say that "request" is not defined in `routes/user.js`

> ReferenceError: request is not defined
>       at Object.module.exports [as handle] (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\node7\routes\users.
>   js:12:5)

Having to include modules in every route which wants to use them doesn't sound like a proper solution...

Comment: Why shouldn't this be a proper solution? It means only to use dependencies that you really need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are two ways of creating global variables in Node.js, one using  the `global object`, and the other using `module.exports`

Here is how,

Method 1. Declare variable without var keyword. Just like `importModName = require('modxyz')` and it will be stored in global object so you can use it anywhere like `global.importModName`

Method 2. Using exports option.
`var importModName = require('modxyz'); 
module.exports = importModName ;` and you can use it in other modules.

Look here for somemore explanation http://www.hacksparrow.com/global-variables-in-node-js.html

Comment: FWIW using `global`, especially like that, is generally frowned upon and can easily end up causing issues.

Comment: Global objects can be used for small projects. As you said, It has to be barely used in large projects.

Comment: Should I duplicate the `app.use()` referencing those included files as well? ie: `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use( bodyParser.json() );`

Comment: Could you answer the my last comment please?

Comment: You dont need to duplicate app.use . Just importing required modules should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave out the `var` and do just `request = require('request');` but this is frowned upon.

Node.js caches modules. The standard approach is to require modules where needed.